# Does an I²C IO Expander needs additional resistors for outputs?

Tags: i2c, pins, communication, mosfet, pull-up

I have following setup (see also schematic in the end)

Arduino Nano is connected via I²C to the PCF8575C ([link](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/8130)) IO Expander.
Both, SCL and SDA have 10kOhm pull-ups to 5V.
The Expander pins are connected to a MOSFET-driver that turns on/off 12V LED stripes.
The Expanders Bus address is set via Expanders A0-A2 pins to 0 (0x20).
The MOSFET driver pins have to be pulled to logic 1 (above 2.2V) in order to turn on the stripe.

Currently Arduino runs an blink example, that turns all Expander IO pins on/off every second (using Arduino Wire Library), but the **MOSFET-driver does not turn on/off any Stripe.**

I can manually turn on Stripes by connecting MOSFET-driver pins to Arduinos 5V (or 3.3V)

The power supply to the IO Expander is O.K.

By measuring the resistance between GND and IO pins of the Expander, I can see that it alternates every second (so I²C communication to the Expander works also)

**Curious thing:** While measuring this resistance (holding the multimeter test leads) to GND and to the IO pin of Expander, the MOSFET-driver turns the Stripes on and off! When I take the test leads away it stops working! **Magic?!**

**What am I missing?** Do the output pins of the PCF8575C need some extra pullup/pulldown resistors or something else?

Thank you in advance!

Schematics:
[image: Schematics]

Comment: What does the datasheet for the chip tell you? (hint: table on page 3...)

Comment: @Majenko oh, I see – I need for each output a 1kOhm pullup (to 5V), right?

Comment: You need *a* pullup - the actual value depends on your application. 10KΩ is probably better than 1KΩ since it will reduce current wastage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to the datasheet (which should always be your first port of call for any chip) the outputs are Open Drain. That means you require a pullup resistor, exactly as if the outputs were simple buttons.

Comment: I need _a_ pullup resistor? So one and not 15 (for each output)? 
Does that mean, I can use single common resistor for all outputs?

Comment: No, one pullup resistor *per pin you use as an output*.

Comment: okay, thank you, I'll test that today! But anyway, how can this "mysterious" behavior with the Multimeter be explained?

Comment: When you measure resistance you are applying a voltage. That voltage is acting like a pullup resistor.

Comment: Adding of missing pullup resistors to the outputs did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Think of the oped drain output (or open collector) as a pin that connects to ground when the device is on. If you connect the anode of an LED to plus and connect the kathode to the open drain pin, then you do not need a pull-up resistor (you may need a current limiting resistor though)

The test leads of the Ohmmeter produce a current to masure resistance, it also provides a current path to ground if the that's where you placed one of the leads. This would explain the **Magic**

More [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_collector) about open collector outputs.